# Any group of order $p^2q$ (p,q primes) is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

This question is from Algebra by Thomas Hungerford , Section : Normal and Subnormal Series.

> Prove that any group of order $p^2q$ (p,q primes) is solvable.

A subnormal series of a group G is a chain of subgroups $G= G_0>G_1 >...>G_n=<e>$. The subnormal series is  Solvable if each factor $G_{i+1}/ G_{i}$ is abelian.

One result is : A finite group G is solvable if and only if G has a composition series
whose factors are cyclic of prime order.

It has  cyclic group of order p and q. Also, there exists a sylow p -subgroup of order $p^2$ , by sylow 3rd theorem. But only two groups of order $p^2$ are $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.  But $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not cyclic.

So, I think this result will not prove it.

I am unable to think of any other result. Can you please help?

Comment: *Hint*: Is it possible to have $n_p>1$ and $n_q>1$ in this case?

Comment: How about this : 1. $p$-group is solvable. 2. group of order $p^2q$ has normal Sylow subgroup.